# Why is an imported pom module not ordered at the beginning of the maven multi-module reactor build?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, maven-reactor, maven-multi-module

I am testing with 2 modules:

```
<modules>
   <module>module-1</module>
   <module>module-2</module>
</modules>
```

Module 1 [imports](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) module 2 in the dependency management section:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

I need (and would have expected) the reactor build to execute module 2 first, since it is effectively an upstream dependency of module 1.

But, module 2 is executed last.

Comment: <dependencyManagement> doesn't actually declare a dependency.. it just says roughly: "use this version when a dependency is declared".

Comment: Agreed, not a 'dependency' in the maven sense, but de facto it is still a dependency in the sense that the rest of the build depends on this information. You could make the same argument for the parent pom (not a dependency), but the reactor still orders it correctly.

Comment: The order of the reactor is based on the topological sorted  `dependencies` (NOT about dependencyManagement)... of the inter modul dependencies..apart from that an `import scope dependency` so called BOM does not influence the order as long as you don't use a dependency from that...Also using a module as BOM is wrong.. use a simply dependency in such cases..

Comment: @khmarbaise That is not true. The reactor also builds the parent pom module, identifies it as an upstream requirement for all modules that extend from it, and orders it before them. Imported POMs serve the same purpose as a parent POM, for setups where a single POM hierarchy is not possible or wanted (as described in docs). Jenkins also identifies imported pom modules as upstream dependencies and triggers them before building the projects importing them.

Comment: The root (or in other words the starting point of the reactor; entry point) is always built first because that one is defining it's children (modules); The point of view is not from children, it is from the root to children first. The order of the children is defined by the dependencies and no; An scope imported pom do not serve the same purpose as a parent pom. (Where is this described in the docs?); What I don't understand is your statement about: `for setups where a single POM hierarchy is not possible or wanted (as described in docs).`?

Comment: here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies (first paragraph)